# How would i go about reading this in?

Tags: c#, file, text

I have this text file with customer, account and transaction information in. Each item appears in the order just mentioned line by line.

```
Dr
James
M
Magee
12/05/1978
12
Dakedon Avenue
Mutley
Plymouth
Devon
PL87TS
babiesrus123
2
54-25-36
2455871265
jennies uni account !!!
02/12/1999
-25.36
2000
8
02/02/2010
OTR
Scottish Highlands Vacations Inc.
-650
-675.36
02/02/2010
C/R
Mobiles Inc  - month 4  cash back 
20
-655.36
05/02/2010
OTR
C.Oldgam Travel Insurance service
-44.55
-699.91
08/02/2010
POS
Wrapping Up.Net
-800
-1499.91
12/02/2010
OTR
Carphone Warehome
-145
-1644.91
17/02/2010
D/D
Leather World - loan repayment
-75
-1719.91
22/02/2010
D/D
park deans - loan repayment
-88.56
-1808.47
02/03/2010
ATM
Stirling University
-120
-1928.47
58-69-71
12455871265
johns uni account !!!
02/12/1999
-25.36
1500
6
02/02/2010
D/D
SUBar Monthly Bill- Plymouth
-259.99
-285.35
02/02/2010
C/R
Monthly allowance
450
164.65
02/02/2010
D/D
SUBar Monthly Bill- Plymouth
-325.36
-160.71
02/02/2010
C/R
Monthly allowance
450
289.29
02/02/2010
D/D
SUBar Monthly Bill- Plymouth
-78.36
210.93
02/02/2010
C/R
Monthly allowance
450
660.93
```

In the above snippet from the file is:
1 Customer
2 Accounts
Each Account has several Transactions.

How would i read this information into a Single? ArrayList Data Structure whilst using get and set methods in classes(Customer, Account, Transaction). Whats confusing me is how would i read in this data and keep track of how many accounts a customer has and how many transactions an account has.

From what i think needs doing is a big nested loop to read the information from the text file and keep track of how much information each item has.

```
Loop through Customer 1
    Loop through Customer Account 1
       Loop through Customer Account 1 Transactions
    Loop through Customer Account 2
       Loop through Customer Account 2 Transactions
Loop through Customer 2
...
```

About the text file:

```
•   Customer ID number --- this is the first customer 1
•   Customer title
•   Customer first name
•   Customer initials  //not required - defaults to null
•   Customer surname
•   Customer date of birth
•   Customer house name or number
•   Customer street name
•   Customer address area  //not required - defaults to null
•   Customer city or town name
•   Customer county
•   Customer postcode
•   Customer password *minimum size is 8 characters in length
•   The number of accounts belonging to this customer ---  equals 2 in this example

    o   Account sort code --- this is the first account of customer 1
    o   Account Number
    o   Account Nick Name //not required – defaults to null
    o   Date the account was created
    o   Current account balance
    o   Account  overdraft limit
    o   Number of transactions available for this account---  equals 2 in this example 

           Transaction Date --- this is the first transaction of account 1
           Transaction Type
           Transaction Description
           Transaction Amount
           Transaction Balance after transaction has been applied to account

           Transaction Date --- this is the second transaction of account 1
           Transaction Type
           Transaction Description
           Transaction Amount
           Transaction Balance after transaction has been applied to account

    o   Account sort code --- this is the second account of customer 1
    o   Account Number
    o   Account Nick Name //not required – defaults to null
    o   Date the account was created
    o   Current account balance
    o   Account  overdraft limit
    o   Number of transactions available for this account---  equals 2 in this example

           Transaction Date --- this is the first transaction of account 2
           Transaction Type
           Transaction Description
           Transaction Amount
           Transaction Balance after transaction has been applied to account

           Transaction Date --- this is the second transaction of account 2
           Transaction Type
           Transaction Description
           Transaction Amount
           Transaction Balance after transaction has been applied to account


•   Customer ID number --- this is the second customer 
•   Customer title
•   Customer first name
•   Customer initials  //not required - defaults to null
•   Customer surname
•   ...
•   ...
•   ...
```

Any help is VERY MUCH apreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You already have the idea for a solution, why don't you start working it out? It's a deterministic format with the numbers (account, transactions) upfront.

Comment: Much clearer dude. @Henk, this is related to another question that he asked. It seems that his method for reading it in isn't working the way he expects.

Comment: @user667430 So a Customer is followed by one or more related accounts and Account is followed by one or more related Transactions?

Comment: @user667430 Is this program ported from Java?

Comment: @Kurtnelle Answer below it did work and read in all of the data nicely. Without a nested loop the data is printed to the list box like Customers then Accounts then Transactions; not in grouped by what each Customer has.  I've tried nesting the loops but that seem to not work  when i go to output the contents of the data onto the screen with a foreach loop visiting each ArrayList is prints out the Customers and Accounts but seems to give each Account every Transaction in the text file.

Comment: +1 for such a organized question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then perhaps this will help:

Update the Customer class with a Generic Account List property.

```
 private int numberAccounts;

        public List<Account> Accounts {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public Customer(string theCustomerNumber, string theCustomerTitle, string theFirstName, string theInitials, string theSurname, string theDateOfBirth, string theHouseNameNumber, string theStreetName, string theArea, string theCityTown, string theCounty, string thePostcode, string thePassword, string theNumberAccounts)
        {
            customerNumber = theCustomerNumber;
            customerTitle = theCustomerTitle;
            firstName = theFirstName;
            initials = theInitials;
            surname = theSurname;
            dateOfBirth = theDateOfBirth;
            houseNameNumber = theHouseNameNumber;
            streetName = theStreetName;
            area = theArea;
            cityTown = theCityTown;
            county = theCounty;
            postcode = thePostcode;
            password = thePassword;
            setNumberAccounts(theNumberAccounts);
            Accounts = new List<Account>();
        }
```

Update the Account with a Generic Transaction List Property

```
public List<Transaction> Transactions {
    get;
    protected set;
}

public Account(string theAccSort, string theAccNumber, string theAccNick, 
               string theAccDate, string theAccCurBal, string theAccOverDraft, 
               string theAccNumTrans)
{
    accSort = theAccSort;
    setAccNumber(theAccNumber);
    accNick = theAccNick;
    accDate = theAccDate;
    setAccCurBal(theAccCurBal);
    setAccOverDraft(theAccOverDraft);
    setAccNumTrans(theAccNumTrans);
    Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
}
```

Comment out your "readData()" method and replace with this:

```
 private void readData() {
            ///read all the data into memory (if you can)
            string[] _data = File.ReadAllLines(inputDataFile);
            Queue<String> _lines = new Queue<string>();
            foreach (string _line in _data) {
                _lines.Enqueue(_line.Trim()); //put it into a queue for convience
            }

            ///iterate through the data and extract the details based on 
            ///known record delimiters.
            while (_lines.Count > 0) {
                Customer _customer = new Customer(
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue(),
                    _lines.Dequeue());
                int _numberOfAccounts = _customer.getNumberAccounts();
                for (int i = 1; i <= _numberOfAccounts; i++) {
                    Account _account = new Account(
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue(),
                        _lines.Dequeue());
                    int _numberOfTransactions = _account.getAccNumTrans();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= _numberOfTransactions; j++) {
                        Transaction _transaction = new Transaction(
                            _lines.Dequeue(),
                            _lines.Dequeue(),
                            _lines.Dequeue(),
                            _lines.Dequeue(),
                            _lines.Dequeue());
                        _account.Transactions.Add(_transaction);
                    }
                    _customer.Accounts.Add(_account);
                }

                ///update the legacy part of the system.
                bankDetails.Add(_customer);
                foreach (Account _account in _customer.Accounts) {
                    accDetails.Add(_account);
                    foreach (Transaction _transaction in _account.Transactions) {
                        tranDetails.Add(_transaction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Comment out your "showListsOfCust" method and put this in it's place

```
private void showListsOfCust() {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Customer c in bankDetails) {
                listBox1.Items.Add(c.getCustomerNumber() + " " + c.getCustomerTitle() + " " + c.getFirstName()
                                   + " " + c.getInitials() + " " + c.getSurname() + " " + c.getDateOfBirth()
                                   + " " + c.getHouseNameNumber() + " " + c.getStreetName() + " " + c.getArea()
                                   + " " + c.getCityTown() + " " + c.getCounty() + " " + c.getPostcode()
                                   + " " + c.getPassword() + " " + c.getNumberAccounts());
                foreach (Account a in c.Accounts) {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(a.getAccSort() + " " + a.getAccNumber() + " " + a.getAccNick() + " " + a.getAccDate()
                                       + " " + a.getAccCurBal() + " " + a.getAccOverDraft() + " " + a.getAccNumTrans());

                    foreach (Transaction t in a.Transactions) {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(t.getDate() + " " + t.getType() + " " + t.getDescription() + " " + t.getAmount()
                                           + " " + t.getBalAfter());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked thanks. But when i do the print out at the foreach statements i prints out everypeice of data under each customer. So: Customer 1, then every transaction in the file. Customer 2, then every transaction in the file.

Comment: So you want to print out the customer then his accounts then that account's transactions then onto the next customer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Define classes for Customer, Account and Transaction
2. Use `System.IO.File.OpenText()` to get a TextReader and use `reader.ReadLine()` to get your lines.
3. Do **not** use an ArrayList, it's outdated. Use `List<Customer>` , `List<Account>` etc.

Edit, after looking at the previous question:

It seems the main step you need to take is to add an Acoounts collection to your Customer class, and a Transactions collection to the Account class.

Just a Sketch:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public List<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }  // collection property

    public Customer()  // default constructor
    {
         Accounts = new List<Account>();

    }

}
```

Now when you have create an account you can use `currentCustomer.Accounts.Add(currentAccount);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
While more customers
  Read Customer Information
  Read Number of Accounts
    Loop for each Account
       Read Account information
       Read transaction count
       Loop for each transaction
         Read transaction information
       End loop
    End loop
End loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading it in could be done as you suggest, with nested loops.  It depends on how extensible this needs to be, if you're certain that the format of the data will never change, you don't need to make a flexible system.

For storing the data, my impression is that you'd want a database, but assuming you want to store it in objects in memory, here's one way you could do it.

You could give the customers, accounts and transactions all an ID number, and store them in Dictionaries.  Then you could give the Customer account a list of ID numbers of its accounts, and likewise give the account a list of its transactions.  This way the Account and Transaction data itself wouldn't be nested inside the Customers.  There are other ways to do it, this is one way.

For example:

```
// Not global variables, you'd have to put them in a class somewhere
Dictionary<int,Customer> Customers;
Dictionary<int,Account> Accounts;

class Customer
{
    List<int> MyAccounts;
}
```

To access an account then if you have the ID, you can use Accounts[id];
For example:

```
foreach(int id in MyAccounts)
{
    var account = Accounts[id];
    // Do whatever with the account here
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful, if I'm missing the point in some way do let me know.  Since you refer to ArrayLists and getters/setters I assume you have a Java background.  The List here is like an ArrayList.  Getters/setters are done in the form of "Properties" in C#.  The Dictionary is like a Map in Java.